# aqueduct db upgrade can't connect to database

Tags: postgresql, dart, aqueduct

- windows 10
- postgres version - 13.0
- aqueduct version - 3.3.0+1
- created the database and user correctly
- created the migration

I can connect to database using `psql`.

postgresql.conf contains `listen_addresses = '*', port = 5432`

**When I enter the command :**

```
aqueduct db upgrade --connect postgres://app_user:password@localhost:5432/app
```

**I get error :**

```
There was an error connecting to the database 'app_user:password@localhost:5432/app'. Reason: unable to connect to database.
```

*I have searched hundreds of sources already. This is a new problem that I am not the only one facing. Nobody has solved it yet!*

*Hero, help me please!*

Comment: Can you connect using `psql` e.g `psql -d app -U app_user -h localhost  -p 5432`? What are the contents of your `pg_hba.conf` file?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, I can.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver pg_hba.conf - listen_addresses = '*', port = 5432.

Comment: Add the previous information to your question. Also answers to following. It will save others from working through the comments. Is `aqueduct` on the same machine as the Postgres server?. Have you looked at the Postgres log to see what it says?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sorry, I'm new to this platform.
Yes, in one machine.
log_destination
-----------------
  stderr
(1 row)
Are you talking about this?

Comment: Actually `listen_addresses = '*', port = 5432` are in `postgresql.conf`. The logging would be done to a file via `stderr`.  Use `SHOW data_directory` in `psql` to find the directory it will most likely be in.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I found. Sorry but I dont understand what exactly should I do?

Comment: Can you please post the pg_hba.conf content? If connecting works with psql and not with aqueduct they might use different methods like ssl vs. nossl.

Comment: post relevant parts of the logfile ...

Comment: @clamp here is the file - https://yadi.sk/d/HWlzBdat2qkQvw

Comment: Try to add `hostssl    all   all   127.0.0.1/32   scram-sha-256` and check that ssl is enabled in *postgresql.conf*. Just a guess though...

Comment: @clamp I added it and changed #ssl = on (it was off). Still doesn't work :(

Comment: changing ssl requires restart...

Comment: @clamp I restarted whole laptop. Still...

Comment: Did you check the log? Can you add it to the Question? And btw. did you remove this comment # from `#ssl = on`?

Comment: @clamp 2020-10-05 00: 56: 00.437 MSK [9716] MESSAGE: entry with hostssl is invalid because SSL is disabled
2020-10-05 00: 56: 00.437 MSK [9716] TIP: Set ssl = on in postgresql.conf.
2020-10-05 00: 56: 00.437 MSK [9716] CONTEXT: line 94 of the configuration file "C: / Program Files / PostgreSQL / 13 / data / pg_hba.conf"

Comment: @clamp yes, I did. Same.

Comment: `#` is a comment sign remove that from `ssl = on` ( and restart the server). But then: What does your logfile say about the failed connection attempts?

Comment: Try `postgres://app_user:password@localhost:5432/app?sslmode=disable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hello brothers in misfortune!*

I found a solution to this problem!

I rolled back the version of **PostgreSQL to 10.14**. It's stable.

**My file `pubspec.yaml` I changed to this:**

```
dependencies:
  aqueduct: ^4.0.0-b1

dev_dependencies:
  test: ^1.0.0
  aqueduct_test: ^2.0.0-b1
```

**BUT IMPORTANT.** Enter the command: `pub global activate aqueduct 4.0.0-b1`

*I couldn't solve this problem for 3 days! I'm happy...*

*I hope I can help someone else.*